# Prevent dragged/dropped div from moving when resizing browser window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I use Jquery draggable / droppable.
I loop out some "DIVs" with PHP:
Also i use Bootstrap as my framework!

```
echo "<div class='elementDiv' id='".$row['id']."' style='width:".$row['element_langd']."px' style='height:".$row['element_hojd']."px'>".$row['element_nr']." | ".$row['element_langd']." | ".$row['element_hojd']." | ".$row['element_vikt']."t</div>";
```

Theese divs are draggable:

```
$('.elementDiv').draggable({
   revert: 'invalid',
   grid: [ 10, 10 ],
   containment: "document",
});
```

When i resize my browser windows the divs stays in they´re parent div.

```
<div class="listElements"></div>
```

Now i drag some divs to another div:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 well" id="flakDiv">
    <div class="flakSideUp">
        dropZone
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when i resize my browser window, the divs that i have dragged to "flakSideUp" moves from right to left as i scale the window.
How can i prevent this from happening?

**CSS**

```
[draggable] { 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
user-select: none; /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */ 
-khtml-user-drag: element; 
-webkit-user-drag: element; 
} 
.listElements{
border: 1px dashed #000;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
}
.elementDiv {
background-color: #dddddd;
height: 35px;
margin: 2px;
cursor: move;
}
.elementDiv:hover {
background-color: #cccccc;
}

#flakDiv{
min-width: 650px;
}
.flak{
width: 600px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.flakSideUp{
width: 600px;
height: 100px;
border: solid 1px red;
}
.flakMiddle{
width: 600px;
height: 50px;
border: solid 1px red;
background-color: red;

//Text
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
.flakSideDown{
width: 600px;
height: 100px;
border: solid 1px red;
}
.nopadding {
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
}
.drop-hover{
background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Comment: would you be able to add a jsfiddle or similar demo? that would help

Comment: I tried, the funny thing was that the problem disapeared in the fiddle...